# JQuery Dynamic Form - Submitting an input box with the same name

Tags: jquery, post, dynamic, submit, dynamicform

i need help with this. I'am using JQuery's Dynamic Form plug-in, it duplicates my input boxes every time I click the '+' button however, the problem comes when i hit the submit button
i cannot retrieve the values of my input boxes through $_POST because they were all of the same 'name'.

How could i change the name of my input boxes when they were duplicated?

HTML:

```
<div id="duplicate3">
        <input id="description" type="text" name = "description"size="40">
        <input id="amount" type="text" name="amount" size="14">
   </div>
        <a href="create.php?state=1" id="plus3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Add">[+]</a>
        <a href="create.php?state=0" id="minus3" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  title="Remove">[-]</a>
```

here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#duplicate3").dynamicForm("#plus3", "#minus3",{
limit:10,
createColor: 'yellow',
removeColor: 'red'
}
);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of quick loops to add a number to each input could work:

```
$("input[name^='description']").each(function(index){   
    var id = "description" + (index+1); 
    $(this).attr("id", id);
    $(this).attr("name", id);
});
$("input[name^='amount']").each(function(index){   
    var id = "amount" + (index+1); 
    $(this).attr("id", id);
    $(this).attr("name", id);
});
```

This will get you:

```
<div id="duplicate3">
<input id="description1" type="text" name="description1" size="40">
    <input id="amount1" type="text" name="amount1" size="14">
<input id="description2" type="text" name="description2" size="40">
    <input id="amount2" type="text" name="amount2" size="14">
<input id="description3" type="text" name="description3" size="40">
    <input id="amount3" type="text" name="amount3" size="14">
...
</div>
```

You could run the loops following the add/remove action, or you could just wait and run them before submitting the form, if you didn't need to reference the inputs for any other reason.